# Defining a non-linear coordinate transformation involving DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, control-systems, coordinate-transformation

This question is related to an other question I've asked yesterday [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130467/normal-forms-in-nonlinear-control-systems). Havin not received a reply, I believe there isn't a ready-made function for non-linear coordinate transformation in order to obtain a normal form of an affine state system as in nonlinear control theory. I wish to address here some of the problems in implementing such a function.

We would have the following non-linear control system:

x' = f(x) + g(x) u

y  = h(x)

**First step**
As is well explained in this book [Isidori](https://www.google.it/imgres?imgurl=http://t0.gstatic.com/images%3Fq%3Dtbn:ANd9GcQ19PA7Z0y2ygEz0rU906NO4LafzT43dmRjuJHXLYnTWVQYKNwB&imgrefurl=http://books.google.com/books/about/Nonlinear_Control_Systems.html%3Fid%3DfPGzHK_pto4C%26source%3Dkp_cover&h=695&w=454&tbnid=uHDZNu7YTbTDKM:&vet=1&tbnh=141&tbnw=92&docid=I1VL4h9jU6glfM&itg=1&usg=__GjvjWDq9NFzMv0IsmK7Nkn0OWdU=&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAnKHP-5PQAhWDDRoKHbx_CrYQ_B0IdDAK), what is firstly necessary is to define a nonlinear coordinate transformation. In order to do this, we ought to firstly define a Lie derivative. I've implemented the following code to do this:

```
QDim[a_, b_] := TrueQ[Dimensions[a] == Dimensions[b]]
Lie[l_, f_, x_] := 
 With[{}, If[QDim[f, x] == True, 
   dl = Table[D[l, x[[i]]], {i, 1, Dimensions[x][[1]]}];
   Sum[dl[[i]] f[[i]], {i, 1, Dimensions[x][[1]]}], 
   Print["Error: dimensional mismatch."]]]
DLie[l_, f_, x_, k_] := 
 With[{}, For[i = 0; t = l, i < k, i++, t = Lie[t, f, x]]; t]
```

Another necessary function to be defined is a function that would calculate the relative degree of the nonlinear control system. This was quite easy as Mathematica has such a function:

```
RelativeDegree[f_, g_, h_, x_] := 
 With[{}, sys = AffineStateSpaceModel[{f, g, {h}}, x]; 
  r = SystemsModelVectorRelativeOrders[sys]]
```

**Second step**. What we ought to do now is define an invertible nonlinear coordinate transformation that satisfies the following conditions. If we call *r* the relative degree defined above,we must have:

phi_1 = DLie[h,f,x,0]

phi_2 = DLie[h,f,x,1]

...

phi_{r} = DLie[h,f,x,r-1]

As for phi_{k} with r < k <= n = Dimensions[x], these coordinate transformations must fulfill the following condition:

DLie[phi_{k},g,x,1]=0

In order that the transformation:

phi={phi_1, phi_2, ... , phi_n}

has a non-singular Jacobian.

How can I achieve this result? The main issues involve the fact that the condition for phi_{k} involves DSolve and thus I would have "constants" like `C[1].` The point would then be to find `C[1]` such that phi has a non-singular Jacobian.

**Example**

```
h = x3;
f = {-x1, x1 x2, x2};
x = {x1, x2, x3};
g = {{Exp[x2]}, {1}, {0}};
r = RelativeDegree[f, g, h, x][[1]];
```

The first r elements of phi would be:

```
phir = Table[DLie[l, f, x, i], {i, 0, r - 1}];
```

As for the remaining n-r elements have to satisfy:

```
DLie[phi3[x], Flatten[g], x, 1]
```

This would correctly output:

```
Derivative[{0, 1, 0}][phi3][{x1, x2, x3}] + E^x2*Derivative[{1, 0, 0}][phi3][{x1, x2, x3}]
```

I would then attempt to solve this equation with DSolve. I should obtain something like this:

```
C[1][E^x2 - x1]
```

Yet I wouldn't know how to ask Mathematica to choose a C[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130467/normal-forms-in-nonlinear-control-systems) that satisfies the non-singularity of the Jacobian of phi.

A correct answer to this example is:

```
phi = {x3, x2, 1+x1-E^x2}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find the desired transformation:

```
u[x1, x2, x3] /. 
DSolve[{D[u[x1, x2, x3], x1] Exp[x2] + D[u[x1, x2, x3], x2] == 0} , 
       u[x1, x2, x3], {x1, x2, x3}][[1]]
trans = % /. C[1][x3] :> (1 - # &)
```

Then use `StateSpaceTransform`:

```
StateSpaceTransform[AffineStateSpaceModel[{f, g, h}, x], 
                   {Automatic, {z1 -> x3, z2 -> x2, z3 -> trans}}]
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to ask you how may I achieve this directly from my Lie Derivative:
'DLie[phi3[x], Flatten[g], x, 1]' The problem seems to be that the argument of the phi3 is {x1,x2,x3}: phi3[{x1,x2,x3}]... this messes up DSolve. How can get around this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. 'DLie[phi3[x], Flatten[g], x, 1]' evaluates to $\text{x1}+e^{\text{x2}} \text{x2}$.

Comment: It shouldn't. It should keep phi3 as an unknown to be found with DSolve as you did with u. @Suba Thomas. Since my final goal is to implement a whole function that does all of this, I wanted to obtain the transformed state space form by simply assigning f,g,h,x.

Comment: I apologize, I have realized your answer perfectly fulfills my request. Thanks again for helping.